# Flipping an inequality sign when multiplying by a negative number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

I came across a question that seemingly breaks the rule of flipping the sign when multiplying or dividing by a negative sign. Here is the equation to be solved.

$$|-x| \geq 6$$

The positive answer is as follows:

$$ -x \geq 6 .$$

Multiplying both sides gives:

$$ x \leq -6 .$$

However, I am confused by the negative answer.

I was able to get the correct answer by doing the following.

$$ -(-x) \geq 6, $$ which then becomes $$ x \geq 6.$$

However, if I apply the negative sign to the right side of the equation when taking the negative answer from the original equation, I get:

$$ -x \geq -6, $$ multiplying that by -1 would mean $$ x \leq 6,$$ which is not the correct answer.

I thought it may be that when I put the negative sign on the right side of the equation to create $$ -x \geq -6,$$ I need to flip the sign. However, that doesn't necessarily make sense as a rule since I don't need to flip the sign if I put the negative sign on the left side when I create $$-(-x) \geq 6.$$

Is there a rule on this? I can't wrap my head around why this happens and am wondering if there's a rule that guides to the correct answer when solving inequalities with an absolute value.

Edit: Fixed error.

Comment: That was a lot of text... but suffice to say that $a\geq b$ implies that $ac\geq bc$ when $c\geq 0$ as well as that $ac\leq bc$ when $c<0$.  In more common words... "*multiplying an inequality by a negative number flips the sign.*"  That is certainly true.  At a glance, I can't figure out what your exact hangup is about this, but I do see that you wrote $-x\geq 6$ on one line and the very next line you wrote $-x\leq -6$, seemingly flipping the sign and multiplying only the right side but not the left by $-1$.

Comment: Easier for this specific question is to note that $|-x|=|x|$ and so your original inequality can be rewritten as $|x|\geq 6$ which you should recognize as having solutionset equal to $(-\infty,-6]\cup [6,\infty)$

Comment: Thanks for noting the error. It has been fixed.

Comment: My main point of confusion is that when I apply the rules of flipping the sign, I seemingly get different answers when I place the negative sign on the right side of the equation than if I do the left. The relevant section starts with "*[however], if I apply....*" I understand that is does not lead to the correct answer, but I don't understand why.

Comment: So then... I'm still not understanding where the confusion is.  $x\leq -6$ is indeed part of the solution set.  Recall this is talking about when $(-x)$ was positive and indeed for $x\leq -6$ you do have $(-x)$ is positive.  Do not confuse $x$ being or not being positive with $(-x)$ being or not being positive.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and apologies for the ineloquence. Let me try again. I'm confused why $ -x \geq -6 $ (which becomes $ x \leq 6$) does not lead to the right answer.

Comment: "*However, if I apply...*"  Where did this line $-x\geq -6$ come from?  The expression with the absolute value may replaced, but just that side.  Recall that (*for real numbers $z$*) we have $|z|=\begin{cases}z&\text{if }z\geq 0\\-z&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.  We started with $|-x|\geq 6$.  We can replace the $|-x|$ part *and only the $|-x|$ part* of that inequality with what it equals subject to the different cases.  Whatever you did to have $-6$ there seemingly as a part of the replacement effect was wrong.  The $6$ isn't being replaced, the $|-x|$ is.

Comment: I see. That is where my error is. Because the negative solution to $ |-x| = 6 $ can be written as $-(-x) = 6$ or $-x = -6$ (which is why I thought the negative sign can be put on the left or right side when taking the negative solution), I erroneously applied the same idea to inequalities.  

If my understanding is correct, I can only apply the negative sign to the $|-x|$. Remembering that will help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: " since I don't need to flip the sign if I put the negative sign on the left side when I create
−(−x)≥6."  Yes you do!  You certainly DO need to flip and it is because you didn't flip that you got the error.  (Why did you think you *didn't* need to flip?)..... Yes there *is* a rule.  And it is *VERY* simple.  If you multiple both sides by a negative number you *ALWAYS* need to flip.  No exceptions.

Comment: fleablood, apologies again for the inaccurate writing. By not needing to flip the sign, I meant that since $-(-x) \geq 6$ has the negative on the left side (the side of x) already, there is no division of the entire equation by a negative number. Thus, I think I don't need to flip the inequality. That is, $-(-x) \geq 6$ shouldn't become $x \leq 6$ when the negative signs in front of the x cancel out.

Comment: Refering to "positive" and "negative" answers is a bad idea.  But if you use it, it is important to know *what* is being refered to as positive.  If we think $|-x| = -x \ge 6$ as the "positive" answer it is $-x$ that is assumed to be positive.  So getting $x \le -6$ is not a "negative" answer.  As $x$ is the "negative" value of $-x$ is completely consistant with the "positive" answer of $-x \ge 6$ as it is $-x$ (not $x$) that is assumed to be positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write:  "The positive answer is as follows: $-x \ge 6$."  I think the cause of your confusion is that you haven't said what "positive answer" means.  I think you are assuming it means that $x$ is positive, and that is your mistake.

Here is a version of your solution that spells out more fully what "positive answer" means:  We consider two cases.

Case 1:  $x \le 0$.  Then $-x \ge 0$, so $|-x| = -x$, and the inequality becomes $-x \ge 6$, which is equivalent to $x \le -6$.  So for $x \le 0$, the inequality is true if and only if $x \le -6$.

Case 2:  $x > 0$.  Then $-x < 0$, so $|-x| = -(-x) = x$ and the inequality becomes $x \ge 6$.  So for $x > 0$, the inequality is true if and only if $x \ge 6$.

Combining the two cases, we conclude that the solution set of the inequality is $(-\infty, -6] \cup [6, \infty)$.

Comment: Thank you, Dan. You are right in that I was incorrect there. The explanation is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay.  The "positive" answer refers to the thing inside $||$ being positive.  If the thing inside $||$ is $-x$ then that is assumed to be positive is $-x$.  If $-x$ is positive than $x$ is negative.

So if we assume $-x \ge 0$ that is the same thing as assume $x \le 0$.

We get $-x \ge 6$.  Multiply by $-1$ ***AND FLIP!!!!*** and we get

$x \le -6$.  Which is *fine* because we are assuming $x \le 0$.

This is a "negative" answer for $x$.... but is a "positive" answer for $-x$.

=======

"I was able to get the correct answer by doing the following.

−(−x)≥6,
which then becomes
x≥6."

But that is NOT the correct answer *if* we are assuming $-x \ge 0$.  In fact that is the *WRONG* answer if we are assuming $-x \ge 0$.

But it is the correct answer if we assume $-x \le 0$.

.....

Basically if we have $|M| \ge k > 0$ we have two choices.

1. If $M \ge 0$ then $|M| = M \ge k$ and $M \ge k$ and that is HALF of the answer.

or

2. If $M \le 0$ then $|M| = -M \ge k$ so $M \le -k$ and that is the other half of the answer

And the answer is $M \ge k$ OR $M \le -k$.

.....

In your case you are dealing with $M = -x$ so the two answers are:

$-x \ge 6$ and $x \le -6$ [that is the "positive" answer for $-x\ge 0$]

OR $-x \le -6$ and $x \ge 6$

[that is the "negative" answer for $-x \le 0$]

.......

If that is too complicated we can always use the fact that $|-M| = |M|$ always (*whatever* $M$ is).

So we have $|-x| = |x| \ge 6$.

So if $x \ge 0$ we have $x \ge 6$ (that is the "positive" answer for $x \ge 0$).  And if $x \le 0$ we have $-x \ge 6$ so $x\le -6$ (that is the "negative" answer for $x \le 0$).

The answer is $x \ge 6$ *OR* $x \le -6$.

....

Consistent answers.

....

Anyway the rule about flipping when multiplying by a negative.  It's very simple.  You ALWAYS flip the inequality when you multiply by a negative.  ALWAYS.  NO EXCEPTIONS.  EVER.